# ClearML - dynamically updating Plotly plots?

Tags: python, plot, clearml

I have a question related to ClearML plot logging. We are currently using:

```
self.task_logger.report_table("TableSpaceName", "Some Info", iteration=0, table_plot=df)
```

To report tables. They appear under "PLOTS" section. Similarly, we are reporting plotly graphs:

```
self.task_logger.report_plotly(
        title="PlotTitle", iteration=0, series='SeriesName', figure=fig
    )
```

Both work fine. The issue is, each new `report_plotly` call, instead of replacing the image in the section, creates a new one, and leaves the previous one present too. This cloggs the PLOTS section (tables and figures). The question is, how does one report a plot, so that it's reported in-place (Such as e.g., scalars, where sample plot gets updated in time)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that ClearML sorts by "title" param. Hence, having e.g., title="Part 1: someStuff" will be placed before title="Part 2: someOtherStuff".

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm part of the ClearML team

Are you providing a fixed `title`, `series` and `iteration` values? If so, this should not happen and is probably a bug